# Реализация css Transform при наведении на блок

Tags: html, css, css3, transform, перевод

Получается сделать transform для любого элемента отдельно, либо трансформацию блока при этом трансформируя блоки внутри него. 
Необходимо чтобы трансформировался весь блок целиком при наведении и при этом не поднимались остальные блоки)

Возможно ли это сделать без JS ?

```css
.row {
  background-color: #343444;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s, border-radius 0.7s, box-shadow 1s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s, border-radius 0.7s, box-shadow 1s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.5s, border-radius 0.7s, box-shadow 1s;
  max-height: auto;
}

.row :hover {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.01);
  -o-transform: scale(1.01);
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px #232323;
  image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.last {
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.last :hover {
  transform: none;
}

.news_last__time {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: right;
}

.news_last__data {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.news_last__tag {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="last">
    <h3>Недавно...</h3>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300/4d494d/686a82.gif&text=placeholder+image" alt="placeholder+image"></a>
    <br>
    <div class="news_last_content">
      <div class="news_last__data"><small><data>12.12.12.2037</data></small></div>
      <div class="news_last__time"><small><time>13:45</time></small></div>
      <br>
      <div class="news_last__tag">
        <a href="#">
          <h4>Короткое название какой-то актуальной новости ...</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, тогда вот мой вариант:

```css
.row {
  background-color: #343444;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s, border-radius 0.7s, box-shadow 1s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s, border-radius 0.7s, box-shadow 1s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.5s, border-radius 0.7s, box-shadow 1s;
  max-height: auto;
}

.row :hover.last {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.01);
  -o-transform: scale(1.01);
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px #232323;
  image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.last :hover {
  transform: none;
}

.last {
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.last :hover {
  transform: none;
}

.news_last_content {
  transform: none;
}

.news_last__time {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: right;
}

.news_last__data {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.news_last__tag {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="last">
    <h3>Недавно...</h3>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300/4d494d/686a82.gif&text=placeholder+image" alt="placeholder+image"></a>
    <br>
    <div class="news_last_content">
      <div class="news_last__data"><small><data>12.12.12.2037</data></small></div>
      <div class="news_last__time"><small><time>13:45</time></small></div>
      <br>
      <div class="news_last__tag">
        <a href="#">
          <h4>Короткое название какой-то актуальной новости ...</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AnatolyMill Обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
.row:hover .last {
   transform: ...
}
```

Вместо `.last` может быть любой вложенный в `.row` элемент. Таких правил можем быть несколько и все они сработают при наведении на `.row`.

Comment: к сожалению ваш вариант не сработал, но вы натолкнули на мысль прописать стили для каждого класса. вышло как то так: 
[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/p2nLfr75/1/) 
однако это полностью не решило проблему. Как видите все блоки при наведении "ходуном ходят"